# Hay alguna forma de ver que objetos utilizan un indice en Genexus?

Tags: genexus

Tengo una KB bastante vieja, que tiene varios indices que fueron definidos para mejorar la performance de reportes. Los reportes han cambiado a lo largo del tiempo y seguramente hay muchos índices que ya no tienen sentido y me gustaría eliminarlos.

Intente hacer un `xRef` del objeto `Index` para ver que programas (procedimientos, webpanels, etc) usan el índice en su navegación pero la lista de "Is Referenced By" siempre esta en blanco - por mas que me consta que el índice se usa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene algún truco para resolver esto?

### Update a la Pregunta después de las respuesta de Marcos:

La pregunta no se enfoca en el uso de los indices en la base de datos - que como bien explica Marcos el DBMS usara o no los indices que definimos en GeneXus  - la intención de la pregunta es mas por limpieza/orden de la KB…

Es decir, si tengo definidos índices definidos en la KB que no se están referenciando (es decir, en la KB no hay ningún objeto que establezca ese Order) es digamos altísimamente probable que el índice no sea usado por el DBMS (a menos que haya tenido mucha suerte! ;). Sin embargo, la existencia del  índice (no referenciado) si afecta negativamente a las operaciones de escritura en la base de datos. Estoy segura que muchas KBs viejas sufren de este problema.

Podría ir borrando indices y tirar una especificación – a ver que objetos reportan un warning por falta de índice – para constatar que no tengo ningún objeto que lo referencie, pero… parecía un poco trabajoso de más.

Otro caso de uso del x-ref para índices me sucede cuando  hay índices definidos que son semejantes – Índice 1: A, B, C  e índice 2: B, C, A, D -  y son candidatos a analizar si no conviene unificarlos en uno solo y para eso es importante entender que navegaciones los usan y analizar si esa separación tiene sentido o no.

Answer (score 3):

Es muy difícil saber desde GeneXus si el manejador de base de datos va a terminar usando un determinado índice o no. Por más que GeneXus diga que va a usar un índice, es posible que luego el DBMS termine utilizando otro por alguna optimización interna que pueda realizar.

Por ese motivo, lo mejor para saber si un índice se usa o no es ver la actividad en la base de datos. Se puede hacer una recorrida por toda la aplicación y registrar las sentencias que se ejecutan, para luego ver qué índices se utilizan.

Answer (score 1):

El DBMS usará el "mejor indice" que pueda en cada consulta que se realiza.
En los índices de clave única, sin duda el menor costo de la consulta para el DBMS será usar el índice.
En el caso de índices de clave duplicada, ni siquiera se puede afirmar que un análisis HOY de como el DBMS realiza la consulta, coincida con un análisis de la misma consulta 6 meses despues.
El índice que utilizará dependerá de los valores que obtiene el DBMS de las estadisticas de la distribución de datos en las tablas que utiliza.
Lo mas "óptimo" desde el punto de vista del DBA, es monitorear las consultas, y efectuar las mismas analizando el costo de cada una (armarse un script con las consultas mas comunes, y las mas "pesadas" y ejecutarlo periodicamente), buscando agregar indices o modificar los existentes si la consulta dispara su "costo" mas alla de valores que entienda convenientes.
El análisis de lo que HOY hace el DBMS no es permanente y debe ser monitoreado cada cierto tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Según el DBMS que use la aplicación existen formas de realizar querys para 
obtener la estadística de uso de sus índices. A manera de ejemplo podemos citar los  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats de MSSQL Server.

De esta manera, no sería necesario realizar ningún x-ref en la metadata de Genexus pues como bien cita Marcos Crispino, aún haciendo un x-ref en la mencionada KB de Genexus no habría garantía alguna de que dicho índice estuviera siendo utilizado por el DBMS en cuestión.-

Este tipo de estadísticas que menciono son usualmente utilizadas por los DBA cuando precisamente hacen mantenimiento de las bases de datos.

[Aquí](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/04/20/how-can-you-tell-if-an-index-is-being-used/) podemos ver un ejemplo de aplicación de las estadísticas mencionadas. En particular observese la parte que describe por ejemplo el número de veces que se utilizó un índice en una consulta de busqueda o actualización de una tabla.